# TypeError tuple indices must be integers or slices not datetime

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror

I am trying to pass a certain index of a record from an object to my main function but when doing so I get this tuple error. Both of the records are time types and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to cause this.. let me know if I can clarify anything further.

load_file.py

```
def get_connection():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT ID, Type, Server, Port, User, Password, isActive, FileExtension, FileContains, FileLocation, "
        "ScheduleMinutes, IntervalTime from DataConnection WHERE isActive=True")

    return cursor.fetchall()


class FileData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.interval_time = None
        self.schedule_minutes = None

    def data_connection(self, data_connection_detail):
        self.schedule_minutes = data_connection_detail[10]
        self.interval_time = data_connection_detail[11]
```

main.py

```
from load_file import get_connection
from load_file import FileData



def run_engine():
    file_data = FileData()
    while True:
        data = get_connection()
        for data_connection_detail in data:
            file_data.data_connection(data_connection_detail)
            schedule_minutes = data_connection_detail[file_data.schedule_minutes]
            interval_time = data_connection_detail[file_data.interval_time]

            download_files(data)
            import_records(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_engine()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve `schedule_minutes` and `interval_time` from `data_connection_detail`, since `FileData.data_connection()` method already does that for you.

```py
def run_engine():
    file_data = FileData()
    while True:
        data = get_connection()
        for data_connection_detail in data:
            file_data.data_connection(data_connection_detail)
===
-           schedule_minutes = data_connection_detail[file_data.schedule_minutes]
-           interval_time = data_connection_detail[file_data.interval_time]
===
+           schedule_minutes = file_data.schedule_minutes
+           interval_time = file_data.interval_time
===
            download_files(data)
            import_records(data)
```